# Can You build a DockPanel like Visual Studio in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, minimize, wpf-4.0, dockpanel

In Visual Studio, we can add various panels like SolutionExplorer Panel, Properties Panel,etc.
Also we can minimize these panels and maximize these panels.

I want to design a dockpanel similar to what I have mentioned in WPF. ( I should be able to pin the panel, unpin the panel, etc)

Does DockPanel support this by default? Or should I do something to support this feature.
A sample illustration of code will be great!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DockPanel is just a common Panel for arranging elements around the edges of the container with the option of having the last element fill the remaining space. It does not do any sort of VS type docking/undocking/pinning/unpinning. For something like that you would need a custom control. You could try a free one like [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) or purchase ones like Infragistics XamDockManager or from the other component vendors.